# In NetLogo, how to create turtles on the road downloaded from OpenStreetMap?

Tags: gis, openstreetmap, netlogo

I am new to NetLogo and currently I wish to simulate turtles to move on the road. I have downloaded street map from OpenStreetMap and just converted into shapefile (only roads) so that it is compatible for NetLogo. But as I use GIS extension to import the road and run the code, it seems that NetLogo couldnt find any roads(blue) and so fail to create turtles on the roads.

```
extensions [gis] 
patches-own [vlocation]

to setup
 clear-all
 ask patches [ set pcolor white ]  ;;set background white
end

;;import the road downloaded from OpenstreetMap
to load            
  let view1 gis:load-dataset "map11_osm_ln.shp"
  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of view1

  foreach gis:feature-list-of view1
  [
    gis:set-drawing-color blue     ;;draw road as blue
    gis:draw view1 0.5 
  ]
end

to add-turtles
  create-turtles 1
  ask turtles       ;; create turtles on road which is blue only
  [
    set vlocation one-of patches with [pcolor = blue]
    move-to vlocation
  ]
end
```

However, I got this error:

```
MOVE-TO expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead.
```

I have inspected the road(patches) and found that pcolor of the roads are all 9.9 not blue. Is this the reason that NetLogo couldn't find any roads to create turtles? How should I do so that I can create turtles on the road?

Comment: "Is this the reason...?" — yes.

Comment: @SethTisue It seems that the roads are too coarse when inspecting at the patch level . I have tried to change the size of patches but still cant work... How should I change the code or with the map? Pls I really need help so thank you in advance!!

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand what your question is.

Comment: @SethTisue I mean how should I do if these vector GIS features (roads) seem more detailed than the size of the patch. Which part of code should I change so that NetLogo can detect the roads? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know, no experience with GIS in NetLogo. Perhaps someone else can answer.